# Defining your own permissions in android

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying make my own permission for android application.

For this my android manifest file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hp.happybirthday" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.hp.happybirthday.PERM"
        android:description="@string/pdesc"
        android:label="@string/CAREFUL"        
      />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:permission="com.example.hp.happybirthday.PERM">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem that I am facing is that I want to have my own permission associated with this application and hence i have added the following line as shown above under the application tag, so that only those activities have access to this app which possess my defined permission.

```
android:permission="com.example.hp.happybirthday.PERM"
```

But the problem is that when I try to run my app, the app whose manifest file I have declared, it shows the error **app is not installed**.

But when I remove the above mentioned line, it works, but then any activity will have access to this app which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to run my app, the app whose manifest file I have declared, it shows the error app is not installed

That is because the home screen is an app, and the home screen does not hold your custom permission. Hence, the home screen cannot start your launcher activity.

> then any activity will have access to this app which I do not want

First, custom permissions [do not work all that well](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Second, permissions are usually applied at a finer granularity than "this app". You only secure those components that need the security, and you leave public other components, like the launcher activity.

Comment: How do i go about it then?

Comment: @JJ: I have no idea what "it" is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've defined the permission, and set it to be required...  but you haven't actually granted it to your own app.  Add a [uses-permission tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)